# change click function to load

Tags: jquery, css

theme/demo : http://prodo.create.rocks/

homepage, on load there is play button, once you have to click, video play with sound and show exit button on bottom. once you hit the exit video sound became mute.

how come to reverse the process, video load with exit button and once you click it will show you play button

```
$('#video-mode').click(function() {
    $(videoModeSelector).animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, {
        duration: 500,
        queue: false,
        complete: function() {
            if(!videoMode) {
                $('.slider').unmuteYTPVolume();
                $('<div />').appendTo('#intro').css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    bottom: '30px',
                    color: '#FFF',
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    opacity: 0
                }).addClass('click-to-exit');
                $('<i />').appendTo('.click-to-exit').addClass('fa fa-volume-off');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.click-to-exit').animate({
                        opacity: 1
                    }, {
                        duration: 500,
                        queue: false,
                        complete: function() {}
                    });
                }, 500);
            }
            videoMode = true;
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your question really is not clear. You've not actually asked a question!

Comment: @Jamiec, I update it, i think its clear now :)